# Primefaces: Modal dialog não abre

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

Estou tentando abrir o Dialog do primefaces, porém sem sucesso. Tenho o seguinte código:

ClientesCadastrados.xhtml:

```
...
<ui:define name="content">
    <h:form id="frm-clientes-cadastrados">
        <p:button value="Novo Cliente" styleClass="btn-cadastrar" onclick="cadastroClienteDialog.show(); return false;" />
            <p:dataTable var="cliente" value=...>
                ...
            </p:dataTable>
    </h:form>
</ui:define>

<h:form id="frm-cadastro-cliente-dialog">
    <p:dialog header="Cadastrar Cliente" widgetVar="cadastroClienteDialog" modal="true">
        Conteúdo
    </p:dialog>
</h:form>
```

No console do navegador da o seguinte erro:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: cadastroClienteDialog is not defined at HTMLButtonElement.onclick (ClientesCadastrados.xhtml:31)

Comment: Se não me engano, no `onclick` do botão você precisa referenciar o form em que o dialog está. Algo tipo: `onclick=":frm-cadastro-cliente-dialog:cadastroClienteDialog.show()"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O onClick não consegue enxergar o seu widgetVar em outro form.

Inclua a sua dialog dentro do seu form 'frm-clientes-cadastrados' ou então referencie o form na sua chamada onCLick.

Exemplo:

```
<ui:define name="content">
<h:form id="frm-clientes-cadastrados">
    <p:button value="Novo Cliente" styleClass="btn-cadastrar" onclick="cadastroClienteDialog.show(); return false;" />
        <p:dataTable var="cliente" value=...>
            ...
        </p:dataTable>
    <p:dialog header="Cadastrar Cliente" widgetVar="cadastroClienteDialog" modal="true">
      Conteúdo
    </p:dialog>
</h:form>
```

Você pode verificar mais exemplos e a documentação no link abaixo:
http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/overlay/dialog/basic.xhtml

Comment: Não é necessário que o dialog fique no mesmo form que o botão. O dialog (ou qualquer outro componente) pode ficar em outro form. Basta o botão referenciar o dialog nesse outro form: `:form-do-dialog:dialog.show()`